# How to send Email with FileAttachment from local disk

Tags: node.js

I am using `node-ews` for sending Email through MicroSoft Exchange using my corporate credendials.

But I cannot figure out how to attach `.xlsx` files to an email from local disk storage. It seems that there is no simple Path tag.

This is what i have

```js
const ewsArgs = {
  attributes: {
    MessageDisposition: 'SendAndSaveCopy',
  },
  SavedItemFolderId: {
    DistinguishedFolderId: {
      attributes: {
        Id: 'sentitems',
      },
    },
  },
  Items: {
    Message: {
      ItemClass: 'IPM.Note',
      Subject: 'Subject',
      Body: {
        attributes: {
          BodyType: 'Text',
        },
        $value: 'Bodytext',
      },
      ToRecipients: {
        Mailbox: {
          EmailAddress: 'email@email.ru',
        },
      },
      IsRead: 'false',
      Attachments: {
        FileAttachment: [{
          Name: 'filename.xlsx',
          IsInline: false,
          ContentType: 'text/xlsx',
          ContentLocation: 'filename.xlsx',
        }]
      }
    },
  },
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `contentLocation`. You need to give the correct path of the file you want to  attach. But you just provided the filename.

`Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel`

Comment: Thank you. I have just tried this. But it is giving an error:
`{"ResponseMessages":{"CreateItemResponseMessage":{"attributes":{"ResponseClass":"Error"},"MessageText":"Required property is missing.","ResponseCode":"ErrorRequiredPropertyMissing","DescriptiveLinkKey":0,"MessageXml":{"ExceptionFieldURI":{"attributes":{"FieldURI":"attachment:Content"}}},"Items":null}}}`

Comment: This what i tried:<code>
Attachments: {
        FileAttachment: [{
          Name: 'filename.xlsx',
          IsInline: false,
          ContentType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
          ContentLocation: 'D:\nodejs\Projects\ProjectFolder\file.xlsx',
        }]
      }</code>

Comment: you don't need to provide path like this D:\nodejs\Projects\ProjectFolder\file.xlsx'. I suppose you put it in public folder your file. provide the path like this './public/filename.xlsx'

Comment: Doesn't work anyway, tried differenct combinations `./file.xlsx`, `../file.xlsx`, `./folder/file.xlsx`
Maybe the tag ContentLocation is wrong? It seems that new file is created everytime with zero content.
Have you used `node-ews` library or some other? 
There is another one `ews-javascript-api` maybe I should try another one?

Comment: Can you try ewsArgs youself and show the case that works for you? I mean sending email with file attachment from local storage?

Comment: can you tell the folder name where you put the file

Comment: same folder as app.js (for simplification)

Comment: check this link below https://github.com/CumberlandGroup/node-ews/issues/40. it is using content not contentLocation.You need to read the file data and put in content  as shown in this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-add-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange